# Proof of Peirce's Law in Propositional Calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is it possible to derive Peirce's Law:

⊢∗ [(α → β) → α] → α

in a calculus that has modus ponens, the Deduction Theorem, Cut rule, Inconsistency effect and Principle of Indirect Proof?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by Inconsistency effect and Principle of  indirect Proof? Neither are standard labels.

Comment: Sorry about that. Inconsistency Effect: If Φ ⊢ , then Φ ⊢ β for every formula β (if Φ is inconsistent, then any formula can be deduced) . Principle of Indirect Proof: If Φ, ¬ α ⊢ , then Φ ⊢ α (If Φ, ¬ α is inconsistent, then α can be deduced from Φ) .

Comment: What you're calling the "Inconsistency Effect" is (much) more commonly called the [Principle of Explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) or "ex falso quodlibet" (often shortened to just "ex falso") or, in some contexts, falsity/bottom elimination though that's often written as $\bot E$.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Peirce's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_law) has good background information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We refer to: Moshe Machover, [Set Theory, Logic and Their Limitations](https://books.google.it/books?id=JzQMbXHpXgkC&printsec=frontcover) Cambridge UP (1996), page 116-on for the definitions and some results about *propositional calculus*.

*Proof*

1) $(ϕ → ψ) → ϕ$ --- premise

2) $\lnot \phi$ --- premise

3) $\vdash^* \lnot \phi \to (\phi \to \psi)$ --- *Problem 8.8* [page 125]

4) $\phi \to \psi$ --- from 2) and 3) by *mp*

5) $\phi$ --- from 1) and 4) by *mp*.

Up to now we have:  $(ϕ → ψ) → ϕ, \lnot \phi \vdash^* \phi$.

Obviously:  $(ϕ → ψ) → ϕ, \lnot \phi \vdash^* \lnot \phi$.

Thus, we can use *Indirect proof* to get:

6) $(ϕ → ψ) → ϕ, \vdash^* \phi$.

> 7) $\vdash^* ((ϕ → ψ ) → ϕ) → ϕ$ --- from 6) by *Deduction Theorem*.