# Proofs using theorems instead of axioms

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, hilbert-calculus

I'm not sure how to prove these basic theorems in propositional calculus. Instead of using the standard axioms, we're supposed to use:

1. Deduction Theorem (if $\Phi, \alpha \vdash \beta$ then $\Phi \vdash \alpha \to \beta$),
2. Reductio (if $\Phi, \alpha \vdash \, $, then $\Phi \vdash \lnot \alpha$),
3. Cut Rule (if $\Phi \vdash \alpha$ and $\Psi, \alpha \vdash \beta$ then $\Phi \cup \Psi \vdash \beta$),
4. Inconsistency Effect (if $\Phi \vdash \, $, then $\Phi \vdash \beta$ for every formula $\beta$), and
5. the Principle of Indirect Proof (if $\Phi, \lnot \alpha \vdash \, $, then $\Phi \vdash \alpha$),

as all the axioms can be deduced using these theorems.

I don't really know how to start the proofs without using the axioms:

i) prove that $\lnot(\alpha \to \beta) ⊢ \alpha$

ii) prove that $\lnot\alpha \vdash \alpha \to \beta$

Any suggestions on how to start these proofs or any insight at all would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Is $\neg$ just a symbol in your system, or is $\neg a$ e.g. shorthand for $a \to \bot$?

Comment: Negation is a symbol in the system. The system is built using negation and implication.

Comment: What does it mean "Reductio"?

Comment: Reductio: If Φ, α ⊢ , then Φ ⊢ ¬ α

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: What is the Cut Rule?

Comment: See Mauro's answer to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635168/proof-of-peirces-law-in-propositional-calculus) for a derivation of ii) (except do only one application of the Deduction Theorem at the end) ... of course this is assuming you have axioms A1, A2, and A3 as indicated by Mauro .. do you have those?

Comment: Yes, using the axioms, the question seems relatively straight forward. However, in the book we are using (Machover's Set Theory, Logic and their Limitations), it says that we should no longer use the axioms once we have these proof-theoretic principles because they contain all the information that the axioms were designed to provide.

Comment: This is why I am confused, I'm not quite sure how to approach the proofs without the axioms. What assumptions can we make, where do we start, etc.

Comment: All of the rules you've listed are of the form "if $\Phi\vdash \Psi$ then..." This means you have no way of starting a chain of logic (more technically called a "derivation"). I suspect, at least, a rule like "$\Phi,a\vdash a$ always holds" is also intended to be in the set of rules you're allowed to use.

Comment: @DiscipleOfKant - What is the exact formulation of the cut rule in your system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that we have the source of your problem, we can help you...

See: Moshe Machover, [Set Theory, Logic and Their Limitations](https://books.google.it/books?id=JzQMbXHpXgkC&printsec=frontcover) Cambridge UP (1996), page 116-on for the definitions and some results about *propositional calculus*.

> *Definition 8.1.*
>
> A set of two formulas $\{ \alpha,  \lnot \alpha \}$, one of which is the negation of the other, is called a *contradictory pair*.
>
> A set $\Phi$ of formulas is said to be *[propositionally] inconsistent* - 
>   in symbols: "$\Phi \vdash_0$" - if both members of some contradictory pair 
>   are propositionally deducible from $\Phi$.

We have to note some results: *Problem 8.12* [page 126]: $\alpha \vdash_0 \lnot \lnot \alpha$, for all $\alpha$, and *Lemma 8.14*: $\lnot \lnot \alpha \vdash_0 \alpha$, for all $\alpha$.

At this point of the book, the *proof system* regarding $\vdash_0$, based on $\lnot$ and $\to$ and the five *axioms* of page 117 plus *modus ponens*, has been enlarged with addiotnal (derived) rules:

> *Theorem 7.2: Deduction Theorem*.
>
> *Theorem 6.13: Cut Rule*: If $\Phi \vdash_0 \delta_i$ for each $i = 1, 2,\ldots, k$ and $\Psi \cup \{ \delta_0, \ldots, \delta_k \} \vdash_0 \alpha$, 
>   then $\Phi \cup \Psi \vdash_0 \alpha$.
>
> *Inconsistency Effect*: If $\Phi \vdash_0$, then $\Phi \vdash_0 \beta$, for every formula $\beta$.
>
> *Reductio*: If $\Phi, \alpha\vdash_0$, then $\Phi \vdash_0 \lnot \alpha$.
>
> *Indirect proof*: If $\Phi \lnot \alpha \vdash_0 $, then $\Phi \vdash_0 \alpha$.

---

Now we have: *Problem 8.19* [page 128]:

> Prove: (i) $\lnot \alpha \vdash_0 \alpha \to \beta$; (iv) $\lnot (\alpha \to \beta) \vdash_0 \alpha$.

We assume to use, in addition to *modus ponens*, also the derived rules above, as well as the already available results.

For (i):

1) $\vdash_0 \lnot \alpha \to (\alpha \to \beta)$ --- *Axiom scheme iv*

2) $\lnot \alpha$ --- premise

3) $\alpha \to \beta$ --- from 1) and 2) by *mp*.

According to *Definition 6.8* [page 117], the above is a *propositional deduction* of $\alpha \to \beta$ from the set of formulas $\Phi= \{ \lnot \alpha \}$ and we can write (according to *Definition 6.9*): $\lnot \alpha \vdash_0 \alpha \to \beta$.

---

For (iv):

1) $\lnot (\alpha \to \beta)$ --- premise

2) $\lnot \alpha$ --- premise

3) $\alpha \to \beta$ --- from 2) and previous result (*Problem 8.19 (i)*).

Up to now we have:

> $\lnot (\alpha \to \beta), \lnot \alpha \vdash_0 (\alpha \to \beta)$

and obviously:

> $\lnot (\alpha \to \beta), \lnot \alpha \vdash_0 \lnot (\alpha \to \beta)$.

This means: $\lnot (\alpha \to \beta), \lnot \alpha \vdash_0$.

Finally, we apply *Reductio* to get:

4) $\lnot (\alpha \to \beta) \vdash_0 \lnot \lnot \alpha$,

followed by *Lemma 8.14*: $\lnot \lnot \alpha \vdash_0 \alpha$, to conclude:

> $\lnot (\alpha \to \beta) \vdash_0 \alpha$.

---

---

*Note.* How to prove (i) with *MP, DT* and *Inconsistency* (without axioms)?

1) $\alpha$ --- premise

2) $\lnot \alpha$ --- premise

Form 1) and 2) we have: $\Phi= \{ \alpha, \lnot \alpha \} \vdash_0$.

Thus, we can apply *Inconsistency* to get:

3) $\lnot \alpha, \alpha \vdash^* \beta$,

concluding, by *DT*, with:

> $\lnot \alpha \vdash^* \alpha \to \beta$.

---

Having proved $\lnot \alpha \vdash^* \alpha \to \beta$, we can use it in the proof of (iv) above (line 3)) to get:

> $\lnot (\alpha \to \beta) \vdash^* \alpha$.

Comment: Superb! Your answer completely clarifies the context of the question in the OP. In my answer I followed what the questioner said in a comment "we should no longer use the axioms". Moreover, I used a formulation of the cut rule that does not correspond to the one used in the book. I think I will delete my answer.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco - why delete it ? The result is fine also for Machover's system as long as you use Machover's result: *Example 6.11*: $\vdash_0 \alpha \to \alpha$ (instead of calling it "Axiom").

Answer (score 2):

As correctly suggested by Derek Elkins in his comment, I strongly conjecture that your system should have an axiom rule of the form $\alpha \vdash \alpha$ (or $\Phi, \alpha \vdash \alpha$) for every formula $\alpha$. I do not know the exact formulation of the cut rule in your system, anyway it should be equivalent to the formulation of the cut rule I used in my derivations.

First, I answer your question (ii). The following is a derivation of $\lnot A \vdash A \to B$ in your system.

1. $\lnot A \vdash \lnot A$ -- axiom
2. $A \vdash A$  -- axiom
3. $\lnot A, A \vdash \ $  -- cut rule (*modus ponens*) of 1. and 2.
4. $\lnot A, A \vdash B$  -- inconsistency effect (*ex falso quodlibet*) from 3.
5. $\lnot A \vdash A \to B$  -- deduction theorem from 4.

Concerning your question (i), the following is a derivation of $\lnot(A \to B) \vdash A$ in your system. It uses my answer to your question (ii).

1. $\lnot (A \to B) \vdash \lnot (A \to B)$ -- axiom.
2. $\lnot A \vdash A \to B$  -- see derivation above, question (ii)
3. $\lnot (A \to B), \lnot A \vdash \ $ -- cut rule (*modus ponens*) of 1. and 2.
4. $\lnot (A \to B) \vdash A$ -- (principle of indirect proof (*reductio ad absurdum*) from 3.