Proof of ((A→B)→A)→A using axioms and hypothetical syllogism
Problem:
Prove
(
(

→

)
→

)
→

((A→B)→A)→A using axioms and hypothetical syllogism (HS).
Relevant Axioms:
Axiom 1 (A1):

→
(

→

)
Axiom 2 (A2):
(

→
(

→

)
)
→
(
(

→

)
→
(

→

)
)
Axiom 3 (A3):
(
¬

→
¬

)
→
(

→

)
Hypothetical Syllogism (HS):
If

→

and

→

, then

→

.
Attempt at a Solution:
1.
(

→

)
→

1.[Assumption for conditional proof]
2.

[Assumption for conditional proof]
3.

→
(

→

)
[From Axiom 1]
4.

→

[Modus Ponens on lines 2 and 3]
5.

→

6.

[From line 2 and HS on lines 5 and 6]
However, I am not sure if this is correct or if I am using the axioms and HS properly. Could someone guide me through the correct steps to construct this proof?
Thank you for your assistance!

Search this site for Peirce's law.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635168/proof-of-peirces-law-in-propositional-calculus

in this we assume ~A or phi in that example , how that can be correct , we can't just assume that ~A .

"4.  →  [Modus Ponens on lines 2 and 3]"  Your post says says 'and hypothetical syllogism'.  Are we allowed to use modus ponens?  Is it part of the formal system?

actually im not sure if im right thats why im here .

See ProofWiki: Peirce's Law does not hold intuitionistically; thus, its proof requires LEM or DN or some other classical equivalent principle.
